# How to have a count on the number of times an <apex:outputLink >has been clicked?

Tags: visualforce, controller

I want to count the number of times an output link has been clicked,and populate that value to a custom field,How can we achieve that?
My code is as follows:

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="NoteExtension" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">

<apex:form >
    <apex:pageblock id="Note" title="Notes & Attachments" >

        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!lstAttachment}" var="a" >

            <apex:column headerValue="Action">
                  <apex:outputLink value="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!a.Id}">View</apex:outputLink>
                  <apex:outputLink value="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!a.Id}">Download</apex:outputLink>
                  <apex:outputLink value="/{!a.Id}">Edit</apex:outputLink>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                  <apex:outputField value="{!a.Name}"/>
            </apex:column>

        </apex:pageblockTable>
                <apex:pageblockTable value="{!lstNote}" var="b">
                      <apex:column headerValue="Action">
                              <apex:outputLink value="/{!b.Id}">View</apex:outputLink>
                              <apex:outputLink value="/{!b.Id}">Download</apex:outputLink>
                              <apex:outputLink value="/{!b.Id}">Edit</apex:outputLink>
                      </apex:column>
                      <apex:column headerValue="Title">
                              <apex:outputField value="{!b.Title}"/>
                    </apex:column>

        </apex:pageblockTable>
         <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
               <apex:commandButton value="New Note"/>
               <apex:commandButton value="Attach File"/>
               <apex:commandButton value="View All" />
           </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Controller class:

```
public with sharing class NoteExtension{

       public List<Attachment> lstAttachment{ get; set; }
       public List<Note> lstNote{ get; set; }

    public NoteExtension(){
        lstNote= [Select isPrivate,Title,Body from Note where parentId=:apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id') ];
        lstAttachment=[Select isPrivate,Name,Body from Attachment where parentId=:apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id') ];

        //Click_Count__c


    }
}
```

Comment: can't you use `onClick` event for this `outputLink`?

Comment: Yes I can add ,but then would the "value" attribute will work as expected?